How can a network card driver cause issues with just one wifi network?
I recently came across a question on Unix & Linux where the OP couldn't use one specific WiFi network, but had no issues connecting to others. Apparently, the system would connect and get an IP but then could not browse. Of course, there could be all sorts of reasons for this, for instance a DNS failure, and that isn't what I am asking about. What piqued my curiosity was a comment by another user, one who I know is quite knowledgeable about networks and certainly more knowledgeable than I am. This user suggested that the problem might be caused by the driver (module) handling the network card on the Linux system.
So my question is, how can a driver issue only affect one specific network? Can it depend on the router hardware? I would have guessed that the hardware details of the router are abstracted by the router's software and a standard protocol is used to communicate with connecting devices, so I am having trouble imagining how the OS driver used by the connecting machine could cause problems with only one specific network.
Can someone give an example of how this could happen, at least in theory?

“So my question is, how can a driver issue only affect one specific network?” - It won’t

Yeah, that would have been my thought as well, @Ramhound, but since I know that this other user knows far more about networking than I do, I was intrigued. Can you explain why this could not happen? That could be an answer. Maybe the driver doesn't support the network's encryption, perhaps? That's handled by the driver, right? But then that wouldn't block browsing, it would block the connection.

I wouldn't say "it won't" though. There are so many "parameters" / variables when it comes to WiFi. If the driver is bugged that it does something wrong with for specific parameter value and only one network that you have access to use that value, then "it could". (IHMO It's a bit similar to the case that many people would think opening a GIF can't get your phone hacked.)

Ah, that's the kind of thing I'm wondering about @TomYan. Could you post an answer with an example of what kind of parameter that might even be possible with? My ignorance is deep here.

Unfortunately I don't have a concrete example for you. What I meant was, to me logically speaking it's at least plausible that something like that could happen. (Think of all the possible options in hostapd.) Though I did bump into a remotely similar problem that I thought "wat? no way", but then: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues/1113 (I mean, IMHO this issue is somewhat even more surprising. Would you even think that a WiFi driver could mess with the content of an IP packet?)
